# What kind of iOS parental gate do I need for older kids (9+ years old kids)

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple rejected my app submission asking for a Parental gate.
I read this https://developer.apple.com/app-store/kids-apps/ and searched on google.
All the examples of parental gates are made for young kids.

My app is a multiplication game made for kids that are older than 9 years old so all the basic maths questions will be too simple for the kid.

What sort of gate should I put for this age? the documentation is very unclear about this.

Comment: Hello, you can use **BODMAS** related questions for parental gate.

Comment: @sammyhp that's a good idea, didn't know this BODMAS rule!

Answer (score 0):

As @sammyhp suggested the BODMAS rule is a good way.

I went a bit simpler, I ask the user to give the result of `n^2` with n between 2 and 10. I got accepted with this parental gate so I guess it's good enough.